# Swift iOS Set scrollView constraint below navigation bar programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

My UIViewController is embedded in a navigation controller. I programmatically add the navigation buttons and now trying to add a scrollView below this navigation bar. The problem I'm having is this is filling the full frame size and going under the navigation bar.

How do I programmatically set constraints of this scrollview?

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var containerView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = "Filters"
    // add some buttons on the navigation

    self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

    containerView = UIView()

    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 21))
    label.text = "my label"
    containerView.addSubview(label)
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

While Clafou's answer is certainly correct, if you don't need transparency and want to start under navigation bar, the really proper way is to change behavior of the ViewController so it fits the content properly. To do that, you have two options:

1) Assuming you have Storyboard, go to ViewController Attributes Inspector and disable "Under top bars"

[image]

2) Assuming you are everything through code, you will want to look for following properties - `edgesForExtendedLayout`, and `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars`. There is [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875322/how-to-set-uiviewcontroller-extend-edges-properties) for that already on SO so I won't cover it here.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 25):

The only way I managed to get this working on iOS11 was like this

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Comment: Just for note - this is not the same `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` of UIViewController.

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 5

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
])
```

Comment: this will make content item of scrollview below navigationbar

Answer (score 4):

While using `auto-layout`, just make sure that you give the `top-constraint` of `UIScrollView` with `Top Layout Guide`, not with `superview` of scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C I usually set the 'edgesForExtendedLayout' Property to *UIRectEdgeNone*:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Nevertheless I would recommend to bind the Constraints to the *topLayoutGuide*

```
func addScrollViewConstraints() {
    var scrollViewContraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    scrollViewContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.topLayoutGuide,
        attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0))
    scrollViewContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.bottomLayoutGuide,
        attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0))
    scrollViewContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0))
    scrollViewContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0))
    self.view.addConstraints(scrollViewContraints)
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

for placing any view under the navigation bar use this code:

```
yourView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/75143442/851258

```
if let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -navBar.frame.size.height, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
}
```