# Prevent Tab Bar from cutting off WKWebView text

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uitabbar, wkwebview

Our UITabBar is cutting off the bottom of our WKWebView text.

Our Storyboard view has a few labels at the top of the screen and a WKWebView set below those labels programatically.  It works great but you can't scroll to the end of the WKWebView to see the last line of the text.

I believe this doesn't happen with UIWebView but that API is deprecated.

I understood `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to be the solution but apparently [that doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21302259/47281) in this case.

Have tried setting [Extend Edges \ Under Bottom Bars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31428932/47281) to false on the Storyboard.  This comes close to solving the issue - the scrolling issue is resolved.  Only issue is the Tab Bar then changes color to a darker color and I can't seem to get that to revert to the default lighter grey metallic color.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of current view hierarchy? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WKWebView contains UIScrollView. UIScollView has contentInset property.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619406-contentinset
Use this property to add to the scrolling area around the content. The unit of size is points. The default value is UIEdgeInsetsZero.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes that is what I ended up doing (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out based on some other SO posts:

```
webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, controller.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.height, 0.0)
```

... maybe there is a better way (?) but this worked.