# UIViewController from XIB not resizing to UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

I've created `MyViewController` in separate xib and pushed it to navigation stack. It is loaded properly and resizing, but hides below the displayed navigation bar (green button hidden):
[image]
In the xib I've set all options of top bar to inferred:

[image]

How can I solve it? Of course I can manually add spacing in the xib, but it's just not the right way.

EDIT:
In xib's attributes I don't see extend under Top Bar tick, since in xib I have created UIView with file owner set to MyViewController.

[image]

[image]

Comment: in xib setting ,in Attribute Inspector -> untick Under top bar and Under bottom bar check box

Comment: I don't have this option in my xib. Will write an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed with changing `edgesForExtendedLayout` property programatically in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeRight | UIRectEdgeLeft | UIRectEdgeBottom;
```

With some help from question:
[How to set UIViewController "extend edges" properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875322/how-to-set-uiviewcontroller-extend-edges-properties)

Answer (score 2):

It is because of translucent. You should do this.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

And you'll see it works. When the navigation bar is not translucent, xib can't locate behind the navigation bar to show what it has.

Comment: Nice answer anyway it is always good if you explain in one or two sentences why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Select your View in xib and the go to attribute inspector

[image]

and select top Bar as shown in screenshot and then design your screen accordingly. It gives you an idea about how much space will your navigation bar take.